# can I set the firebase notification datetime from my web ASP.net web api using firebase sdk

Tags: asp.net, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am planninig to send firebase notification but in specific date-time
like 20-12-2020 10:30
from my ASP.net web api
is that possible
I am using firebase admin library
and sending notification is work completely
my code for sending is like the next

```
        var message = new Message()
        {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                ["client"] = client.Name + "," + client.Mobile,
                ["source"] = order.Source,
                ["click_action"] = "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
            },
            Notification = new Notification
            {
                Title = "new Order",
                Body = client.Name + "," + client.Mobile + "," + order.Source + "," + order.Destination + "," + order.Id,
            },
            Token = driver.Token,
        };

        string response = await messaging.SendAsync(message);
        Console.Write(response);
```

Comment: There is no way to schedule delivery of FCM messages through the API. The only options are to: 1) schedule delivery through the Firebase console, 2) deliver a **data** messages through the API right away, but then programmatically decide when to display it in the `onMessage` handler, 3) schedule delivery of the message in your own ASP.NET back-end.

Comment: thanks Frank, i will try on the third solution .. I just want to check the options and you give me what i need ...